# Поиск с выпадающим списком по всем данным таблицы Asp Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Не могу реализовать поиск с выпадающим списком по всем данным таблицы, нужно помощь в решении этой задачи.
Сейчас выдает список, только с полем менеджера. Если я вожу компанию, то в список выпадает, тоже менеджер из этой компании. Получается поле менеджера основное?

[image: Работа автопоиска]

Контроллер выглядит так.

```
   public ActionResult AutocompleteSearch(string term)
        {
            var a_suppliers = db.Ue_suppliers.Where(
                a => a.ShortName.Contains(term) ||  a.Manager.Contains(term)
                || a.Name.Contains(term) || a.PhoneManager.Contains(term)
                || a.Phone.Contains(term)
                ).ToList().Select(
                a => new { value = a.Manager, a.Name, a.ShortName, a.PhoneManager, a.Phone
                }
                ).Distinct();

            return Json(a_suppliers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Вот так выглядит view.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:1em">
    @Html.Partial("_LeftMenuUchet")
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8" role="main">
        <div class="bs-docs-section">
            <h1 class="page-header">Поставщики</h1>

            <div class="row">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Ue_Suppliers_Search", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
                {
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="input-group" style="display:flex !important">
                            <input type="text" name="name" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("AutocompleteSearch", "Uchet")"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   placeholder="Поиск по поставщикам" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Искать</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

                <div class="pull-right col-lg-1">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" data-modal="" href="/Uchet/Create_Ue_Suppliers" id="btnCreate">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="margin-top:2em" >
                <div class='contacts' id="results">
                    @Html.Partial("_Suppliers_Content")
                   </div>
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/Appjs/UeType.js")
<script>
    $(function () {
     $("[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
         var target = $(this);
         target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") });
     });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Мне нужно, что бы  при наборе номера выпадал номер, при наборе названии компании выпадало название компании и тд. а сейчас работает, только по менеджерам.

Comment: в качестве идеи: var a_suppliers = db.Ue_suppliers.Select(a => new { value = a.Name.Contains(term) ? a.Name : null });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо объединить подходящие значения из колонок, в которых происходит поиск, в единый линейный массив строк. Примерно так:

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteSearch(string term)
{
    var a_suppliers = db.Ue_suppliers
        .Where(a => a.ShortName.Contains(term))
        .Select(a => a.ShortName);

    a_suppliers = a_suppliers.Union(
        db.Ue_suppliers
            .Where(a => a.Manager.Contains(term))
            .Select(a => a.Manager));

    a_suppliers = a_suppliers.Union(
        db.Ue_suppliers
            .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(term))
            .Select(a => a.Name));

    a_suppliers = a_suppliers.Union(
        db.Ue_suppliers
            .Where(a => a.PhoneManager.Contains(term))
            .Select(a => a.PhoneManager));

    a_suppliers = a_suppliers.Union(
        db.Ue_suppliers
            .Where(a => a.Phone.Contains(term))
            .Select(a => a.Phone));

    return Json(a_suppliers.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо!